# CSS transition height performance - most performant choice of transitioned element and method?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I can't really seem to evaluate or find any sources myself, stating which of the following examples should yield the best result performance-wise. Therefore I'm turning to you guys, hoping that you can enlighten the subject.

I have a fixed header which on mobile devices are expanding it's `height` to show the navigation menu. However, I'm not quite sure whether it's better to expand the parent's (container's) height, or only expand the height of the actual menu.

I'm well aware that transitioning height isn't the best option performance-wise, however it gives the animation which I prefer in this case.

**In short:** I believe my main question is whether animating the container's height results in the most rendering, painting and compositing, compared to animating the menu itself?

Also, any other notes on how to improve the animation is welcome. I'm well aware of hardware acceleration and creating a new composite layer (e.g. `translateZ(0)`), so it's more with regards to animating the "correct" element.

Besides the above, am I missing something which could improve the transition/animation performance?

You can see two examples below.

First example, expanding height of the container:

```css
body,html{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.fixed{
  position:fixed;
top:0;
height:50px;
background: #ddd;
width:100%;
box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #000;
transition: height .4s ease-in;
}
.menu-wrap{
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  bottom:0;
}
.menu{
  position:relative;
}
.fixed:hover{
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
Header
<div class="menu-wrap">
<ul class="menu">
<li>Point 1</li>
<li>Point 2</li>
<li>Point 3</li>
<li>Point 4</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="page-content">
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
</div>
```

Second example, expanding the menu itself:

```css
body,html{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.fixed{
  position:fixed;
top:0;
height:50px;
background: #ddd;
width:100%;
box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #000;
}
.menu-wrap{
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  bottom:0;
  height:0px;
  transition: height .4s ease-in;
  background:#ddd;
}
.menu{
  position:relative;
}
.fixed:hover .menu-wrap{
  height:calc(100vh - 50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
Header
<div class="menu-wrap">
<ul class="menu">
<li>Point 1</li>
<li>Point 2</li>
<li>Point 3</li>
<li>Point 4</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="page-content">
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
Page content<br>
</div>
```

Comment: benchmark both of them and see the difference of which one is better or maybe both are equivalent.

Comment: Well i've been using Chome Dev Tools to see the timeline/performance, but haven't been able to tell whether there's a difference. It might just be because there isn't any difference, but I just find that odd